# httpmodule isn't being called on certain requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-8, httpmodule

I am new to ASP Net programming and I am trying to create a custom HttpModule that will block MS-DOS device names (AUX/CON/prn/clock$/NUL/COM1/LPT1/LPT2/COM2/COM3/COM4/c:.). I am working in IIS 8.0.

At first I am trying to create a test module (straight from the msdn tutorial on how to create a module)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        application.EndRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<h1><font color=red>" +
                "HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request" +
                "</font></h1><hr>");
        }
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<hr><h1><font color=red>" +
                "HelloWorldModule: End of Request</font></h1>");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

and I have this in my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So my test module does get called when I type a normal request such as localhost/Hello but it does not get called when I type in a request such as localhost/AUX. Instead it goes to a server error page.

Is there any configuration I need to set up in order for my module to be called when I type in a request localhost/AUX ?.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563818/how-can-i-create-an-http-handler-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-html-pages

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! Unfortunately it is still not working for me :(

Comment: Can you confirm that you have added the following setting into your web.config file? <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it still does not work for device names such as localhost/AUX